# jQuery, 'denyClass' extension sought after

Tags: jquery

I would like to write a jQuery 'plugin' that essentially accepts a CSS class and denies it from ever being added to a given selector. Is this even possible? I cannot figure out how to actually intercept the `addClass` method and check it without going into the jQuery source code - and my experience with javascript is not nearly strong enough to be comfortable trying that. Plus I am loading jQuery through a CDN, so I'd rather not muck around in its source.

Comment: Well, you could do a little monkey punching I guess... `var oldAddClass = $.fn.addClass; $.fn.addClass = function (cls) { if (!/classIdontwant1|classIdontwant2/.test(cls)) oldAddClass.call(this, cls); return this;};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could overwrite it like this if you accept hardcoding denied classes. You can add this anywhere, it will simply 'patch' jQuery with an enhanced `addClass` function.

http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/A8ePY/1/

```
(function($) {

// keep copy of original function
var old = $.fn.addClass;

$.fn.addClass = function(classes) {
    var spl = classes.split(" ");

    // remove denied class if present
    if(spl.indexOf("denied") > -1) {
        spl.splice(spl.indexOf("denied"), 1);
    }

    // pass everything to original function (altered classes plus other arguments)
    return old.apply(this,
                     spl.concat([].slice.call(arguments, 1)));
};

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: A good idea, but unfortunately the classes won't be hardcoded. Otherwise I would just run a large statement to clean them out myself.

Comment: @Stacey: Then you could create a `denyClass` as you describe, which adds denied classes to some array. Then inside the patched `addClass`, iterate over that array and decide which classes to remove.

Comment: The problem I am having is wrapping my head around how to store the 'selector-class' association. I do not want to deny a class for everything, I want to deny it on a specific selector. My javascript is a paltry, pathetic excuse for passable and I am having a great deal of difficulty conceiving of the best approach for this. Is it okay to just store objects by their selector into an array, such as `var object = $('selector');`? I fear that would be very resource intense.

Comment: @Stacey: I'm not sure if building a 'dictionary' with selectors/denied classes is a very good option. Perhaps there is a better solution for your scenario. E.g. why are you adding classes to selectors when you deny them? Why would you need such a function at all?

Comment: because jquery plugins like to add a lot of their own classes, and a lot of the themeroller classes - and there are several situations when i want to make sure that a certain class does not get applied to something.